# JScrollPane is not scrollable in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, scrollbar, jscrollpane

I am using this code to add a **scroll panel** in my **JFrame**

```
JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(getContentPane(),
    JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, 
    JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
this.setContentPane(pane);
```

I can view the scroll-bar but it is **not scrollable** even after resizing the window.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Comment: Why are you adding the content pane to the scrollpane??

Comment: How else can I add my already created jframe to a scroll panel

Comment: I guess this is good reason not to add your content directly to the frame, but instead add the core UI to something like a `JPanel` and then add that to the frame...or in chunks there in, but that's me...

Comment: but I did, :( and I cant start it from the initial stage again:(

Comment: If scrollpanel is adding this why thn it should also b scroll able? aah my bad

Comment: [Same Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116433/jscrollpane-scrollbars-not-scrollable) Hope it Will help u !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yupii!!!!!!
Got the solution of my problem.
I just need to add

```
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 900));
```

to my contentpane.
Thanks For every one.

Answer (score 2):

use this code it worked for me

```
    container.setSize(1800, 1500);
    container.setVisible(true);



    container.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 900));
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(container);  
    scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);  
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);  

    add(scrollPane);
```